# Lodash: Transform single value with array of functions

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm looking for `lodash` function that able to transform/map/filter a single value with array of functions, for example:

given value to be: `" a, b ,c"`

and then call lodash with function like: `_.transform(value, functionList)`

which `functionList` is array of functions to `split` and `trimEach`.

expected result is `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

---

UPDATE:

Thanks for @vlaz, `_.flow()` is that what I'm looking for.

The example I gave above is illustrated the purpose of function. I'm not looking for how to split and trim string (sorry, may be my english is not good enough).

To answer my own questions (and my example), the example code is:

```js
function split(v) {
    return v.split(',')
}
function trimStrArray(v) {
    return _.map(v, _.trim)
}
var fn = _.flow([split, trimStrArray])

console.log(fn(" a, b ,c"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: You can compose functions using `_.flow`, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @vlaz that's it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using `Array.prototype.reduce()` or `_.reduce()`. The reduce is invoked on the array of functions:

```js
function transform(value, functionList) {
  return functionList.reduce(function(result, fn) {
    return fn(result);
  }, value);
}

var value = " a, b, c";

function split(value) {
  return value.split(',');
}

function trimEach(value) {
  return value.map(function(item) {
    return item.trim();
  });
}

var functionList = [split, trimEach];

var result = transform(value, functionList);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`_.split`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#split), [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#map) and as callback [`_.trim`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#trim);

```js
var string = " a, b ,c",
    result = _.map(_.split(string, ','), _.trim);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```